# Flex Mobile Project: List

Tags: list, apache-flex, mobile

I am developing a mobile application in which I want to use a list which contains 400 rows. I got data from Sqlite database. When I run the application and click the button for the list, the list view is loading so slowly and takes about 45 seconds. I also tried getting data from an arraycollection inside the application but I had same problem. Is this normal? Any idea or advice for this issue?

```
                    sqlStat.text="SELECT City FROM Cities";
                    sqlStat.execute();
                    dataArray=sqlStat.getResult().data;

                    appModel=AppModel.getInstance();

                    if(appModel.cities == null)
                    {
                        appModel.cities = new ArrayCollection();
                        var obj:Object;
                        for( var i:int=0; i<dataArray.length; i++ )
                        {
                            obj = new Object();
                            obj.Name = dataArray[i].City

                            appModel.cities.addItem(obj);

                        }
                    myList.dataProvider=appModel.cities;    
                    }
```

Comment: Show some code!   Also do you know where the bottleneck is?  Is it in loading the data?  Or in rendering the list?  Which version of Flex are you using?  I've noticed significant performance improvements in Flex 4.6 / AIR 3.1 over Flex 4.5 / AIR 2.6

Comment: sqlStat.text="SELECT City FROM Cities";
sqlStat.execute();
dataArray=sqlStat.getResult().data;
appModel=AppModel.getInstance();
if(appModel.cities == null)
{
appModel.cities = new ArrayCollection();
var obj:Object;
for( var i:int=0; i<dataArray.length; i++ )
{obj = new Object();
obj.Name = dataArray[i].City
appModel.cities.addItem(obj);
}
myList.dataProvider= appModel.cities
}

Comment: This is my sql code getting the Cities from database and add them into my arraycollection which is defined in appModel class. Then I defined the dataprovider for my list component. This works on creationComplete event of my view. While the view is loading, it takes about 45 seceonds.

I am also using Flash Builder 4.6 and AIR 3.1

Comment: If I reduce the data,e.g. 50, loading time is also reduced.

Comment: Don't post code in comments; it's hard to read.  Edit your question and add the code there.  Make sure you 'highlight' it and press the curly bracket button in the editor to format it as code.

Comment: I added code to my question. By this code I got Cities from database and add them into my arraycollection which is dataprovider for my list. Arraycollection is defined in a class named appModel.

Comment: ok I solved my problem. ListForm component causes renderer problem. I used List component instead of that and created arrayCollection dataprovider for my list inside my class. It works faster than previous.

Comment: Okay, then post that as a formal answer to your own question and select it as such.

Answer (score 1):

The OP wrote:

> I solved my problem. ListForm component causes renderer problem. I used List component instead of that and created arrayCollection dataprovider for my list inside my class. It works faster than previous.

Comment: ([Answered in a comment and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments).)